# Binary addition which disapproves carrying

Tags: python, binary, addition

I'm currently working with binary addition which returns False if there is carrying. My current code is :

```
def binaryadd(one, other):
    str_1, str_2 = str(one), str(other)
    for a,b in zip(str_1[::-1], str_2[::-1]):
        if a == b == '1':
            return False
    return int(bin(rev_bin(one) + rev_bin(other))[2:])
```

so 10111 + 1000 would return 11111, 10110 + 1011 would return False. I think there would be more efficient codes ;such as to check overflows in addition, but I'm wondering which code could do it. Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is carry from the moment there is a "column" for which both operands have a `1`, since in that case we *generate* a carry. A carry can also *propagate*, but only if there was already a carry generated.

We can check this with a bitwise and (`&`). In case there is no carry, we can just is a bitwise or (`|`):

```
def binaryadd(one, other):
    if one & other:
        return False
    return one | other
```

or in a one-liner:

```
def binaryadd(one, other):
    return not bool(one & other) and one | other
```